# popping from the stack without having pushed

Tags: assembly, stack

I am learning High Level Assembly language at the moment and have been going over the concept of the stack. I think I understand it fairly well, however in practice I have some questions.

The stack grows down, with the ESP register always pointing to the top of the stack..an address in low memory. If something is pushed onto the stack, then ESP should be decremented.

EBP is useds as a frame pointer and as to my understanding, should always be more than ESP.

Yet, with the following program:

```
stdout.put(esp, nl);
stdout.put(ebp, nl);
push(ike);
stdout.put(esp, nl);
stdout.put(ebp, nl);
push(ike);
stdout.put(esp, nl);
stdout.put(ebp, nl);
pop(eax);
pop(eax);
pop(eax);
pop(eax);
stdout.put(esp, nl);
stdout.put(ebp, nl);
```

This does not seem to be the case. Looking at the output:

0018FF6C
0018FF70

0018FF68
0018FF70

0018FF64
0018FF70

0018FF74
0018FF70

EBP is always the same, ESP is decremented by 4 bytes for the first push, then another 4 bytes for the second push.

It is after this I am confused. After my first 2 pops, ESP should be back to where it started. How can I then do a further two pops if I have not pushed anything on to the stack? What am I popping?

Further popping and printing out of EAX shows some numbers, and then 0's and then further numbers. So, I am definitely popping something...but what? What part of my program memory does it belong to, and why is nothing being affected?

Why is EBP not being affected at all?

Also, why is ESP being decremented by 4 bytes, and not by 8?

If someone could help me to understand this, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EBP doesn't get modified by push/pop instructions, it's setup manually, so unless you change it yourself it will just stay the same.

The pushes of IKE are resulting in 4-byte changes, so apparently you're in 32-bit mode here.

The 4 pops of EAX (32-bit) will result in a 16-byte (10h) change, just like they do.

Not sure what the problem is here.  Seems to be working as I expect?

Comment: I have no doubt it is working as it is meant to, it's just that I don't understand it. I thought that while EBP was setup manually..., if not done so it was also used internally sometimes? I would have thought ESP would decrement a byte at a time, not 32 bits at a time?

Comment: My main question is why I can continue to pop things of the stack that I didn't push on. Essentially, if I remove the push insctruioncs from my program, why can I pop without having pushed? What am I popping? I am popping of the stack into EAX, but I am not sure what it is I am taking from the stack.

Comment: A further question about EBP...I thought it was always part of the stack, before the return address...

Comment: EBP is just a register.  Typically used for indexing items on the stack (due to standard conventions).  If you really want, you can use it for other things though.  Nothing magic about it.  If you're pushing/popping 32-bit items, ESP will change by 32-bits.  It's a pointer, NOT an item counter.  It has to point to the proper part of memory, therefore it must change by the size of the operands.  The processor is more than happy to pop until it can't pop anymore.  Pop is basically just a MOV then ADD ESP, operand size in bytes.  Real mode, it'll wrap.  Protected may segfault eventually...

Comment: SO using EBP as a frame pointer is just convention, and always done manually -- never internally? It was my understanding that if you coded in a high level language and disassembled, you would see EBP being used.

I get that the processor is happy to pop...but what is it popping? Data from other programs? From operating system memory space?

Comment: EBP as a frame pointer is a convention.  All the compiler makers I'm aware of do follow it, so you should see it anytime you disassemble high-level language output.  By no means a hardware requirement though.  The processor will POP whatever is there.  Doesn't have to be data, could even be uninitialized space if for some reason the stack didn't start at segment top.  Could be popping off the call return address, whatever else should still be there from earlier!  Always pop off as much as you push on.  No more, no less (unless you like weird side effects).  :-)

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, it is really helping as I continue to learn this. It is my understanding that every process runs it its own virtual address space, so if the only thing my program does is to start popping things of the stack, does that mean it is going to corrupt some other process? What effect would a never ending loop of pops do?

Comment: If everything's setup properly, you should segfault if you try to pop outside of your memory space.  Shouldn't be able to affect the OS or other processes.  The virtual address space is setup by the OS though, one could certainly have an OS that throws everybody in the same space.  It would be a bad design, but the hardware allows for it...

Comment: So I'm just popping off stuff within my allocated memmory space? Can I run out of stack so to speak?

Comment: Sure, you can have a stack underflow.  As to what the result is, it's OS dependent.  I believe that the hardware will wrap around in real mode.  In protected mode, I'm not so sure.  Even if it does wrap, it'd probably still segfault.

Comment: So, further testing shows that I can pop 37 times without ever having pushed on to the stack. Poping onto eax and displaying eax always shows some random data. What would this data be...anyway to tell? Should I make this a seperate question?

Comment: Probably subject for a separate question.  "What's already on the stack before my code is called" or something similar.  It'll be VERY much OS dependent!

Answer (score 0):

The stack is used to hold, besides the things you push and pop, every function's stack frame (i.e. local variables), return address, the old ebp (specifically where the current ebp is) and function's parameters. So what you're popping out is the stack frame of your function.
If you disassemble a program, you'll see:

```
push    param3          ; suppose func takes 3 parameters, they're
push    param2          ; pushed in reversed order (C-style)
push    param1
call    func            ; call pushes also the return address, i.e. the
                        ; address of the instrucion after the call

...

func:
push   ebp              ; this is done for preserving the caller's stack frame
mov    ebp, esp         ; now we set up the beginning of func's stack frame
sub    esp, smth.       ; and its width, enough to fit all func's variables
```

At this point the stack will be something like:

```
        00000058:    arg3
        00000054:    arg2
        00000050:    arg1
        0000004c:    return address
 ebp -> 00000048:    caller's ebp
        ...          ...               -
        00000034:    random stuff       |  func's stack frame, random because they
        00000030:    random stuff       |  are uninitialized
 esp -> 0000002c:    random stuff      -
```

Finally, you push and pop only 4 bytes at time because that's the word size of your machine, this way you can save entire registers. in one shot